# Is it safe to keep working in Visual Studio whilst doing a check-in?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I've been through all the `Visual Studio` Source Control documentation and so on but I can't find an answer as to whether it's safe to keep working in `Visual Studio` whilst it's doing a check-in?

We're using `Visual Studio 2015` with `Visual Studio Team Services` source control.

Sometimes there's one or more files (like video files) that take a while to check in, sometimes an hour or more.  I'm worried that if I keep working (specially if I work on the same files that are busy checking in) it'll corrupt the process.

Comment: Generally you can. But if you are going to work on a file that is in the process of checking in, well this is something I will avoid.

Comment: @KumarC Thanks for that info, I'm looking for a definitive answer though.  I am not sure if the `source control` widget will actually make a copy of the file before uploading or if it will upload the file in place.  I'm also not sure if it'll add newly changed files to the check-in or not, hence the reasoning for my post.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting videos in source control, honestly.

Comment: @DanielMann Where would you recommend they go?

Comment: A digital asset management tool. Think of it as source control, but specifically designed to handle versioning large binary objects. Source control systems are optimized for small text documents and are generally a bad fit for binaries in general, but especially for large binaries.

Comment: @DanielMann I guess that does make sense, let's turn the question upside down then (since it happens sometimes), when on a slow connection and the check-in is chugging away on a standard (but large) check-in, what are your thoughts on continuing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it is safe as TFS won't check the changes again after you click check-in button. It just check in the changes you made before click check-in. So edit the file does not affect the check in process.

But in some case, for exmaple, the internet access is disconnected during check-in, then you click "Refresh" button to reconnect to TFS service. The changes will be refreshed too. That means the changes you made during checking is been included now. And there isn't any way to restore to the version that you'd like to check in.

So, you'd better avoid this as possible as you can and check in large files when you are not working with them.